# Querying @ElementCollection Map

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

My Entity uses a field for parameters with data type Map. I can save these objects to DB without problems. But how can I query for them?

```
@Entity
public class ActionData {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "parameter")
    private Map<String, String> parameter = new HashMap<>();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "work_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private Work work;

    @NotBlank
    private String actionName;

    private Instant requestTime;
    private Instant startTime;
    private Instant endTime;

    // ...
}
```

I tried a Repository this way:

```
public interface ActionRepository extends CrudRepository<ActionData, Integer> {

    ActionData findFirstByWorkAndActionNameAndParameter(Work work, String actionName, Map<String,String> parameter);

    // ...
}
```

I try to query for a specific ActionData with parameters:

```
Work work1 = new Work("xyz", "title1");

Map<String, String> parameter1 = new HashMap<>();
parameter1.put("key1", "value1");

ActionData actionData = actionRepository.findFirstByWorkAndActionNameAndParameter(work1, "action1", parameter1);
```

Than I get this exception:

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [{key1=value1}] did not match expected type [java.lang.String (n/a)]`

Spring wants a String type but it is a Map. Why does it not work and how to get this working?

Java 8, Spring 5, Spring Boot 2

Comment: you cannot do it with repository methods. You need to write `@Query`

Comment: OK, if there really is no way - how can this be done with SQL? I even didn't find a solution to compare ALL parameter keys and values.

Comment: @pvpkiran Can you elaborate? Any resources you can add?